# How to implement threadsafe list?

Tags: c#, list, concurrency, thread-safety

I want to implement a threadsafe list, but the thread safety has to be ensured on the whole block of operations, not only on a single operation (eg. add, remove etc.) The use case should look like following:

```
list.Lock();

list.Add(sth);
list.RemoveAt(4);

list.Unlock();
```

I want the list to require the lock for any operations. For example:

```
list.Add(sth);
```

called without prior locking should result in exception. This is why I don't use the `lock()` statement - lock checking is crucial for this solution.

Implementing such list using Monitor is not hard - but only until one wants to check, whether the list is locked or not. I thought of the following scenario:

```
// Inside list class

private object lockObject;
private bool locked;

public void Lock()
{
    Monitor.Enter(lockObject);
    locked = true;
}

public void Unlock()
{
    Monitor.Exit(lockObject);
    locked = false;
}
```

Unfortunately, this code is prone to race conditions - regardless of whether `locked` is set prior or following to entering or leaving the critical section.

Another approach involved using TryEnter, but this method actually enters the critical section if the lock is not obtained, which may also lead to race conditions.

How should I implement this mechanism to be thread safe and how to avoid race conditions while checking, whether list is locked or not?

Comment: Leaving aside my proposed solution, I'd say your implementation issues could be addressed by using compareAndSet (which I'm not sure how is it called like in the C# world)

Comment: as a side note, are these of any help? [Thread-Safe Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make *your* class responsible for the locking and only expose one method which accepts an `Action` that the consumer specifies:

```
public class LockedCollection
{
    private class CollectionImpl : ICollection<int>
    {
       //Collection methods
    }

    private sealed class CollectionWrapper : ICollection<int>, IDisposable
    {
       public CollectionWrapper(CollectionImpl inner)
       {
           _inner = inner;
       }
       private CollectionImpl _inner
       //Collection methods all just wrapping calls to inner
       public void Dispose()
       {
          _inner = null;
       }
    }


    private CollectionImpl _instance - new CollectionImpl();
    private object _lock = new object();

    public void DoStuff(Action<ICollection<int>> task)
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            using(var wrapper = new CollectionWrapper(_instance))
            {
                task(wrapper);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The consumer can have any sequence of operations they like inside `task`, and you know that the lock is taken - because you took it yourself.

Comment: I like this solution very much, but this is not perfectly safe: someone may hack himself outside the protected block: `lc.DoStuff( (ICollection<int> c) => { localVariable = c; } );`

Comment: @Spook - actually, you can deal with that issue by creating another class that implements `ICollection` and acts as a wrapper for the real collection. You create a new one of these, pass *that* to `task`, and when `task` returns, you `Dispose`/invalidate the wrapper class so that it can no longer access the collection. (Make sure that the dispose/invalidate is in a `finally` block)

Comment: Your solution seems to provide atomicity, but no transactionality across sets of operations.

Comment: @vemv - the set of operations that should occur together should be placed inside a *single* `Action`.

Comment: Oh, the naming mislead me. Anyway, making `Action` a 'scalar' operation and passing a list of Actions instead seems like a better design to me.

Comment: @vemv - the naming's not ideal on the outer method either, but I was just trying to knock together a basic example (My first attempt was just to describe this solution but I floundered there, which is when I decided to do it as code instead)

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking of something that would resemble to the Builder pattern.

Example usage:

```
list
    .do() // mandatory initial statement.
          // Doesn't acquire a lock - it just builds a transaction object

    .add(42) // Add an operation to the transaction object.
             // Call would be illegal without performing do() before

    .removeAt(0) // Another added operation

    .end(); // Acquire the lock, perform the specified changes, release the lock.
```

The lock acquisition to be performed by `end()` could be a plain call to `sync {...}` - there are no possible race conditions.

Comment: This is not a direct solution, but a very elegant workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Note that in your proposed API, one may forget to `unlock()` - or an exception could get thrown before reaching that line.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a standard locking mechanism if you provide a getter for the object used as a lock. **While I don't think that this is an elegant solution, it will certainly do the trick.**

```
void performOpertations(TSList list) {
  lock(list.getLock()) {
    list.add(obj);
    list.remove(obj2);
    // do your stuff
  }
}
```

Since C# synchronized blocks are reentrant, you will be able to call internally synchronized methods of the list like `add()` or `remove()` in the example.

Another solution would be to **use the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)** and have the visitor actions surrounded by synchronized block.

Comment: If you can use java synchronized blocks in C#, I'm impressed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks for pointing it out. The answer doesn't change much, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any reason not to use [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
class MyThreadSafeList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> internalList = new List<T>();
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim lockSlim = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();

    public void EnterReadLock()
    {
        lockSlim.EnterReadLock();
    }

    public void ExitReadLock()
    {
        lockSlim.ExitReadLock();
    }

    public void EnterWriteLock()
    {
        lockSlim.EnterWriteLock();
    }

    public void ExitWriteLock()
    {
        lockSlim.ExitWriteLock();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!lockSlim.IsWriteLockHeld)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        internalList.Add(item);
    }

    public void Remove(T item)
    {
        if (!lockSlim.IsWriteLockHeld)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        internalList.Remove(item);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (!lockSlim.IsReadLockHeld)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            return internalList[index];
        }
        set
        {
            if (!lockSlim.IsWriteLockHeld)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }

            internalList[index] = value;
        }
    }
}
```